# How to serve 100Gb of random information?

Tags: ubuntu

My ISP charges me if my server downloads more then uploads. Now I have 2 linux machines. How to make one of them send 100Gb of random information to another and don't create large file on disk?

Comment: That is one not-so-smart billing scheme...

Comment: Got it. I need to use netcat: `<endless stream> | nc -l 1234` and at another host `nc <first host> 1234 > /dev/null`. Now all that remains is to figure out how to write 100G to input pipe.

Comment: cat /dev/zero ou cat /dev/urandom. It won't be limited to 100G so you should watch out.

Comment: urandom causes additional load, so i'll use zero. Also i figured out that i can pipe it to `head -c <bytes>` to limit file size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the final solution is:

Sending machine

```
 cat /dev/zero | head -c <bytes> | nc -l <port>
```

Receiving machine

```
nc <sending ip> <port> > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this to generate 100GB of random data?

```
cat /dev/urandom | head -c 100000000000
```